# Spring-Data-LDAP alternative for "in" query

Tags: spring-data-ldap

Is there any alternative for IN queries in Spring-Data-LDAP?
I'm facing a problem in order to retrieve users from an email list:

The Spring-Data query is something like the following:

```java
this.ldapUserRepository.findByEmailIn(emailList);
```

where `emailList` is a `List<String>` and the error is the following:

```
IN (1): [IsIn, In] queries are not supported for LDAP repositories
```